# "Last activity" shown as being from 127.0.0.1, due to http proxy on LAN?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, last-activity, proxy

On my account page, it shows my last activity as being from 127.0.0.1.

My guess is because my browser is configured to use a HTTP proxy on 127.0.0.1, and maybe that proxy is setting some X-Forwarded-For header?

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but our shared function to get the user IP does check some HTTP headers in the case where the reported IP is localhost.